# How to display all rows from an AdvancedDataGrid, without scroll?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, advanceddatagrid

I have an Advanceddatagrid that has its variableRowHeight property set to true. I need this AdvancedDataGrid to have its verticalScrollBarPolicy "off" also.

How can I show all rows in that AdvancedADataGrid? (Need to set its height in a so manner that it will be visible all its rows).

Thanks.

Comment: You can set its Height 100% but its limited to wrapper height, Which type of Wrapper you are using? simple HTML generated by Flex builder or any other?

Comment: I'm working on desktop environment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the container your `DataGrid` is in is tall enough to fit all of the rows, you can set the `rowCount` property to the number of records in your `dataProvider`. This will show all of the returned rows with no scroll bar.

```
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{myDataProvider}" rowCount="{myDataProvider.length}">
  <mx:columns>
    Your columns go here...
  </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: But my grid needs to have set the variableRowHeight property to true, so your suggestion doesn't work! I have already tried it.